# Django: Cannot assign "(<Sections: xds>,)": "Announs.section" must be a "Sections" instance

Tags: django

In Models i have this:

```
   section = models.ForeignKey("Sections", verbose_name='Раздел')
```

My Views:

```
def announs_add(request):
  if request.method == 'POST':
        form = add_form(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            cd = form.cleaned_data
            section_obj = get_object_or_404(Sections, id=cd['section']),
            announ = Announs(section=section_obj)
            announ.save()
            form = add_form()
  else:
       form = add_form()
  return render_to_response('announs/announs_add.html',
  {
    'form':form,
  }, context_instance = RequestContext(request), )
```

If i try for example add something, i have this:

```
Cannot assign "u'\u041d\u0443\u0436\u0434\u0430\u044e\u0442\u0441\u044f \u0432 \u0442\u0432\u043e\u0435\u0439 \u043f\u043e\u043c\u043e\u0449\u0438'": "Announs.section" must be a "Sections" instance.
```

Help me to fix this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This extra comma:

```
                                                         # v-- this one
section_obj = get_object_or_404(Sections, id=cd['section']),
```

creates a tuple (a 1-tuple containing the section). Remove the comma.

```
section_obj = get_object_or_404(Sections, id=cd['section'])
```